# passing a variable to every response on handlebar

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I am using nodeJS express and handlebars

Is there a way to pass same variable to every express route?

I have to pass `isAuthenticated` variable to every frontend in order to render views slightly differently. I would like to be able to pass a variable in the express middleware so it is rendered in every page. (doesn't have to be through middleware if there is a better way of doing it)

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything you put in `res.locals` will be available to your handlebars template.  So, if you set `res.locals.isAuthenticated` in middleware for every request, then it will be available for all your templates.

In fact, there's an example very similar to yours in [the Express doc](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.locals).